# .net RSACryptoServiceProvider.Encrypt analogy in java

Tags: java, android, .net, rsa

I tried to move some code from .net to JAVA. And I stacked on a simple method:

```
public static byte[] EncryptData(byte[] plainBytes)
{
 RSACryptoServiceProvider publicKeyCrypto = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)platformCertificate.PublicKey.Key;
 var encrypted = publicKeyCrypto.Encrypt(plainBytes, false);
 return encrypted;
}
```

In JAVA I used:

```
RSAPublicKey rsaKey = (RSAPublicKey)platformCertificate.getPublicKey();

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
                cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, rsaKey);
                byte[] cipherData = cipher.doFinal(plainBytes);
```

But the java code result doesn't decrypt correctly on the server side.

Could somebody please provide some information about what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It seems like the java `RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding` implementation is different than the .NET implementation you used earlier. What about using `Cipher.getInstance("RSA");`(don't add a padding)?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Actually I have tried, but it doesn't work too. And that's the strange thing. I think the answer should be somewhere on the surface and I just can't see something obvious. May be use some different library? Can android java have different  suitable library?

Comment: What do you mean with `it doesn't work`? What do you expect? What is the actual output? How does the server try to decrypt it?

Comment: The result I need is to encrypt open key from the certificate and pass it as a part of JWT token to the platform side, where the platform should decrypt the key and it will be the conformation, what the client is valid. I have full working code in .net, but I am a new one in Java. I tried to reproduce it in java and according to my research the problem is in the decryption section. Because then I just copy the encrypted data from .net and pass in in Java code everything just works well. So the snipped from question is actually works, but it encrypts data in a different way.

Comment: Is it because of [Random paddings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28algorithm%29#Padding_schemes)?

Comment: That's the only thing I wondering about now, so I spent some time with different Cipher.getInstance() parameter, but doesn't found the working one. I am not so sure, what this is the problem, but I am searching in this way. Unfortunately I have no access to platform code, but I can provide any other code from .net client or from java client if it will helps.

Comment: You may be able to just test the encryption offline (if it is the same in java and .NET).

Comment: Are you sure the `platformCertificate` is imported correctly?

Comment: That's the good thought - about certificate. I just compare the thumbprints on both .net and java code and it's the same. But is it a correct way to handle public key as `RSACryptoServiceProvider publicKey = (RSACryptoServiceProvider) platformCertificate.PublicKey.Key`  in .net. and `RSAPublicKey rsaKey = (RSAPublicKey)platformCertificate.getPublicKey()` in Java?

Comment: It seems correct...Can you try to encrypt some data without the platform in java and .net? Is it the same?

Comment: I will try, but is it correct what the result of encryption will be different every time even with the same input data and the same public key, because now it's looks like this and it seems strange.

Comment: *...But the java code result doesn't decrypt correctly on the server side...* is not a useful description of the problem. What is incorrect about it? How do you know it is incorrect? Are there any exceptions thrown? Also, where is the code from the server side?